# Validation always Runninng - Even When fail

Tags: asp.net, validation, server, submit

So, i have a simple table and one `RequiredFieldValidator`.
The simplest Code of all and still, the server runs even when it fails to pass the validation

Validator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="FnameReg" runat="server" ErrorMessage="הכנס שם פרטי"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

table: (its 2 tables inside one table)

```
    <table border="0" style="opacity:0.9">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#BCA795;font-size:xx-large;color:white;text-align:center">
            הרשמה</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top">
            <%--@@@@--%>
            <table border="0" style="background-color:white;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:right;width:250px">
                <tr>
                    <td dir="rtl">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="BuildStyleReg" runat="server">
                                  <asp:ListItem>באדי-בילדינג</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem>פאוור-ליפטינג</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem>סטריט-וורקאאוט</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem>לא מתאמן</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:RadioButtonList>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; background-color: #BCA795; color: white">

                        סוג אימון</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td dir="rtl" style="text-align:right">


                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="TargetReg" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="מסה"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="חיטוב"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="ניטרלי"></asp:ListItem>

                   </asp:RadioButtonList>

                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; background-color: #BCA795; color: white">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;

                        תקופת מטרה</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td dir="rtl">

         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="sadas" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Text="טבעי"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="תוספי תזונה"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="טבעונית"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>

                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; background-color: #BCA795; color: white">
                        תזונה</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2" style="background-color: #957860" align="center">

         <input id="SubmitReg" type="submit" value="שלח" style="color: #957860; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: xx-large;" />                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top">

            <%--@@@@@--%>

            <table border="0" style="background-color:white;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:right;width:250px">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="auto-style6">

                                    &nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="FnameReg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                             </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" class="auto-style6">

                                    שם פרטי</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="LnameReg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    שם משפחה</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="EmailReg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    אימייל</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

            <asp:TextBox ID="PassReg" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    סיסמא</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="auto-style3">

            <asp:TextBox ID="RepassReg" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td class="auto-style3" style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">


                                    אימות סיסמא</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

            <asp:TextBox ID="CellPhoneReg" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    פלאפון</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

           <asp:TextBox ID="DateReg" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    תאריך לידה</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">בחר עיר</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">תל אביב</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">יפו</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">ירושלים</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">מודיעין</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">אילת</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6">מעגן מיכאל</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7">חיפה</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="8">שוהם</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="9">לפיד</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">רמת גן</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    עיר</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

            <asp:TextBox ID="AdressReg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    כתובת</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>


            <asp:TextBox ID="CommentReg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="50px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>


                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    הערות</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

            <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageReg" runat="server" Width="25%" />

                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color: #BCA795; color: white; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">

                                    תמונה</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
        </td>

        <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </td>
            <td style="padding:7px;margin:7px;color:red">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" BackColor="White" DisplayMode="List"></asp:ValidationSummary>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

why its always loading the server??

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `ValidationGroup` value to your **validator** and the **TextBox** control , like this :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="FnameReg" runat="server" ValidationGroup="CheckOrSomething"></asp:TextBox>
```

The ValidationGroup value must be the same in both controlls.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="FnameReg" runat="server" ErrorMessage="הכנס שם פרטי" ValidationGroup="CheckOrSomething"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And you can assign `CausesValidation=True` to the `Button`.

Comment: Solved : I had to put Asp:button

Comment: You can use any **Postback controll** . You just have to include `ValidationGroup` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I had to use asp:button instead of input submit